Strange rendering of 3d surface with pgfplots
I'm trying to use pgfplots to plot the following 3d surface (as it comes out of mathematica)

but by using the following pgfplot code which contain the exact same equation as the mathematica code
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{fpu} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={
        sp(\X) =
            1+0.5*(exp(-2*abs(\X-90))+exp(-2*abs(\X+90)));
    }]
        \begin{axis}[%
            axis equal,
            width=10cm,
            height=10cm,
            axis line style={draw=none},
            ticks=none,
            enlargelimits=upper,
            view={45}{0},
            scale uniformly strategy=units only,
        ]
        \addplot3[%
            surf,
            z buffer = auto,
            samples = 21,
            variable = \u,
            variable y = \v,
            domain = -90:90,
            y domain = 0:360,
        ]
        ({sp(u)*cos(u)*cos(v)}, {sp(u)*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {sp(u)*sin(u)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Spindle}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

I get a strange rendering of the surface

and I cannot understand why. Also by having more samples the result is the same.

Changing what is a possible error in your equation gives the expected result (so it is not the exact same equation):
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
line join=round,
declare function={sp(\x)=1+0.5*(exp(-2*abs(\x-90)*pi/180)+exp(-2*abs(\x+90)*pi/180));}
]
\begin{axis}[
axis equal,
width=10cm, height=10cm,
axis lines=none,
view={45}{0},
]
\addplot3[
surf,
z buffer=sort,
samples=21,
variable=\u, variable y=\v,
domain=-90:90, y domain=0:360,
]
({sp(u)*cos(u)*cos(v)}, {sp(u)*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {sp(u)*sin(u)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you very much! I see that the problem then was with having radians rather than degrees in the sp function. A bit of a stupid mistake! My bad.
